# C++ Printing: Printer jams, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, winapi, printing

I have a problem with printing in C++. As far as I know, this code used to work on my previous printer, but ever since I got another one (an HP C7280) it started giving problems. Whenever I try to print anything, even an empty page, the page JAMS the printer. I have to manualy remove the page from the printer. I have no clue why this is happening. Am I doing something wrong, is it a driver problem, are there better ways to print in C++? I am using Windows 7 64 bit, but this problem also presented itself when I was using Windows Vista 64 bit. I use the following code:

```
PRINTDLG pd;
ZeroMemory(&pd, sizeof(pd));
pd.lStructSize = sizeof(pd);
pd.hwndOwner   = mainWindow;
pd.hDevMode    = NULL;
pd.hDevNames   = NULL;     
pd.Flags       = PD_USEDEVMODECOPIESANDCOLLATE | PD_RETURNDC;
pd.nCopies     = 1;
pd.nMinPage    = 1;
pd.nMaxPage    = 0xFFFF;

if (PrintDlg(&pd)==TRUE) 
{
    DOCINFO di;

    di.cbSize       = sizeof(DOCINFO);
    di.lpszDocName  = "Rumitec en Roblaco Print";
    di.lpszOutput   = (LPTSTR)NULL;
    di.fwType       = 0;

     // Start printing
    StartDoc(pd.hDC, &di);
    StartPage(pd.hDC);
    initPrinter(pd.hDC);

    // ...
    // Do some drawing
    // ...

    // End printing
    EndPage(pd.hDC);
    EndDoc(pd.hDC);
    DeleteDC(pd.hDC);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Alternatively, is there a better, easier, more modern way to do it?

EDIT: I can print from ANY other application without paper jams. Notepad, Word, etc, every other application can print just fine.

Comment: Try to print a test page through Windows printer settings, I'm betting the page will jam as well. I find it unlikely this would be a software problem.

Comment: What @avakar said. Paper jamming is a hardware problem, not a software problem.

Comment: Perhaps it is that call to cJamPrinter().

Comment: You're obviously printing too many words on the page, and the ink is clogging the tubes

Comment: @avakar and JS Bangs: I can print just fine from any other application and a test page is no problem either.

Comment: 22,000 google hits on "hp c7280 paper jam".  How many customers use your software?  Get another printer.

Comment: Try printing that to a PDF/postscript file or the Microsoft document writer thingy (forgot the exact name). Use the corresponding visualization software to see that the graphic makes sense. Then try printing that file using the visualization software. Perhaps there's a certain graphic combination that triggers a bug in the printer driver or firmware.

Comment: Is it just me, or does it seem like these printer companies never bother to apply lessons learned from previous printer models?

Comment: Could it be that you are loading the printer with Pop-Tarts, rather than paper?

Comment: @Emile:  Sure they do.  They learned very well that if they create shoddy printers, you'll just go ahead and buy another one!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you CAN cause a printer jam with software. Just print right to the edges - which not many apps do - and you could easily uncover a printer hardware/driver issue where printing near an edge cause the head to jam into the paper.